# Iterate through a DataTable and Save Data in another Database - all dynamic

Tags: sql-server, windows, vb.net

I have been tasked with making a VB app to move SQL tables from one server to another based on certain criteria. The tables are in a variety of databases and the schema could be potentially different on each table.

So far I am:

1. Creating a list of tables that meet the criteria
2. For Each table

   a. Read Current Schema

   b. Recreate the Table on another Server

   c. Read data from the orriginal table and write it into the new Table

There will be more steps to follow but the last step is where I am stuck.

I am reading the data from the Table, My array of data to transfer looks good when debugging. But the destination table never recieves the data, it is always empty.

Here are the two steps in the process that I am struggling with.

```vb
Private Sub MoveData(dbName As String, TableName As String)
    'Read Data from production server and move to Archive Server
    Dim constring As String = "Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=" & dbName & ";User ID=username;Password=password"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using table As DataTable = New DataTable
            Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & TableName, con)
                Using adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                    adapter.Fill(table)
                End Using
            End Using
            For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                SaveInArchiveDB(TableName, table.Rows(0).ItemArray)
            Next
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub SaveInArchiveDB(TableName As String, DataRow As Array)
    Dim Query As String = "INSERT INTO " & TableName & "_Archive VALUES (@DataRow)"
    Dim constr As String = "Data Source=ArchiveDB;Initial Catalog=ArchiveData;User ID=username;Password=password"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Query, con)
            Try
                con.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DataRow", DataRow))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                IO.File.AppendAllText("/WO_Error_Logs/Log.txt", String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", Environment.NewLine, Date.Now(), Environment.NewLine, ex.Message))
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    con.Close()
                End If
                Exit Sub
            Finally
                con.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't really create dynamic sql that represents multiple columns and then just set one parameter. Why did someone ask you to do this? There are far, far better ways to get data from one database to another, especially for sql server replicated things like this.

Comment: This would be much simpler if I was going just to another database, but the database is on another server. This was our driven by our engineers that feel that cramming 100's of machines data into one server for years on end would effect the performance. They want all data over 3 years old moved to a different server.

Comment: You really should consider moving your connection string to the config file instead of hard coding them in your app. I agree there are a lot of better ways of doing this type of data movement. There is also a big missing piece of this. If the intention is to move data from one database to another you need to delete the data from the source once the movement is complete. This kind of process is ideal for SSIS.

Comment: Yes, we copy plenty of data to another database (a bunch, actually) that don't live on the same server. SQL Server has things for this. We use replication. SSIS is great, but it requires the expensive version of sql server so we are phasing it out where I currently work due to licensing costs.

Comment: Anyway, if for some reason I had to manually roll this sort of thing, I would define table valued parameters for each table I needed to move and use those. Dynamic sql like this is just so ripe for sql injection and bugs, it would save a ton of issues down the road to just take a little time to build something more robust out.

Comment: If you want to get fancy or are very familiar with an ORM, you can also leverage nhibernate or Entity framework to do this. Again you'd need a model for each table, but the strong typing and heaving lifting done by the ORM would be a boon for you.

Comment: consider using the SqlBulkCopy class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) if you can load up data into a tablename, you give SqlBulkCopy the destination table name, and it will insert it more efficiently than row by row.

Comment: Thanks for the advice so far @Nikki9696, I haven't seen any examples of using SSIS for doing a task like this. I will have a look.

Comment: @SeanLange, moving the connection string to the config file would normally be the way to go. But as I go through the DataTable each row will be in a different database on the server.

Comment: Jeremy, SqlBulkCopy looks good. I will give it a try, Thanks.